# NativeScript Vue + Fastlane - Custom iOS/Android project path?

Tags: android, nativescript, fastlane, nativescript-vue

I am considering using [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) with [NativeScript Vue](https://nativescript-vue.org/) and wondering how I can setup the whole thing...

Is someone know how to set iOS/Android project path instead of executing `fastlane init` on iOS/Android project folder? 
The problem is that NS build will override the folders where iOS/Android projects are.

Any clue/help will be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently working on upgrading our cross platform docs but in the meantime you can manually create the `fastlane` directory with the `Fastfile` inside of it.

```
mkdir fastlane
touch fastlane/Fastfile
```

Running `fastlane init` does do a lot of nice magic setup my creating this but with a template `Fastfile` and some other configuration files but just creating the `fastlane` directory and the `Fastfile` inside of it what is minimally needed.

To make sure things are working, you could put the following in your `Fastfile` and then run `fastlane test`

```
lane :test do
    UI.message "This is working"
end
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the answer!

Comment: Just a single question : is it possible to programmatically run `fastlane init` and automatically answer question or simply ignoring them? I'm trying to script a thing to do that for me using custom `Fastfile` templates for iOS/Android...

Comment: did this really answer your question? How did you tell fastlane to use the project in `platforms/ios` and `platforms/android`?

Comment: @joshdholtz Can you clarify on how to do `fastlane init` inside a Nativescript-script project with the custom path to iOS/android platforms which are created by Nativescript CLI cmd `tns build` ?